# Contact Form Widget, to make it use by another website

Tags: javascript, widget

I have to create a Contact Form widget — a block of code that users can paste into any site(And i want it to use by my client websites) that will contain a small form, I read so many blogs and code I come up with the answer that Vanilla Js is best for my requirement, I want some refrence or blog or code to make it possible.
 I have plenty of ideas for how to do this, but I'm curious to know if there's any generally-accepted method for including the styles, JavaScript, etc. The best I can come up with now is a  block that fetches all the necessary styles and tags from an external URL.

Comment: _“The best I can come up with now is a block that fetches all the necessary styles and tags from an external URL.”_ - and, what’s wrong with that? // Another common approach would be to use an iframe; but then handling cross-domain communication (where necessary, for example to automatically resize the iframe element to the size of its content) becomes a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad subject and the solution will depend on how much integration or isolation you'll want with the host page. If you want your contact form to always look the same, an iframe is indeed the right solution but has limitations. Popups from your form won't be able to *escape* the iframe. Vertical sizing can be an issue, you may want to look into [Pym.js](http://blog.apps.npr.org/pym.js/) to deal with this.

Note that this doesn't mean you need to provide client websites with the HTML code for the iframe. You can just give them a script tag which points to a JavaScript program that is in charge of building the iframe.

If you want the form to integrate seamlessly with the client site, inheriting styles, then your script will need to inject your form into the page, either using the DOM API or using `innerHTML`. Then it will take some trial and error to figure what CSS properties you'll want to enforce and what can be inherited from the host page. You'll need to namespace your CSS classes and work with [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). It's not always simple and never completely bulletproof, so if you can stick with an iframe you'll be safer.

In both cases, in order to know where to inject your form, you can use the script tag itself as a reference, for instance by giving it a unique data attribute that your script will use to find its own script tag and insert the form below or underneath it.

For a complete coverage of the subject, I can highly recommend the book *Third-Party JavaScript* from Manning.